# Xcode black bars appear to right of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I'm having an issue with Xcode and storyboards. When I build and run my project,
I get a black bar to the left of everything

[image]

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Are you using a LaunchScreen storyboard or images from the xcassets? I ask because if you are using images in xcassets then it is possible that they are the incorrect size.

Comment: I'm using a LaunchScreen storyboard @RichmondWatkins

Comment: Hmm that is very strange then. Are you sure the project is recognizing that you are using the LaunchScreen? I've seen this issue a few times and its always a result of an improperly configured launch screen. Wish I could provide more but that's all I have.

Comment: @RichmondWatkins yup, the LaunchScreen works fine. Really odd

Comment: Are you using autolayout.??

Comment: @DhruvKhatri yup, I am.

Comment: Check your autolayout constraints some times it leads problem like this. Can you post snap of it.?

Comment: Do you have a constraint set to margin where you didn't mean it to be?

Comment: I don't have constraints set, because when I set them it causes all of my other views to not function correctly